# how to check role permission in vaadin-flow forms?

Tags: java, spring-boot, forms, spring-security, vaadin-flow

Hi there I am using vaadin flow 24 with spring boot 3 and spring security 6. I am creating vaadin view with a form component where some fields should only be editable for "Admin" role.

I can render the form components editable or read-only according the current role with `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities()` but I am wondering if there exist a more efficient way in case you have to create many forms?

My Security Utility Class

```
public class BackendAuthorityUtils {
    ...
    public static List<String> getAuthorities() {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        final List<String> authorities = auth.getAuthorities().stream().map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).collect(Collectors.toList());       
        return authorities;
    }

    public static boolean hasAuthority(String authority) {
        if(!authority.startsWith("ROLE_")) authority = "ROLE_" + authority;
        List<String> authorities = getAuthorities();   
        return authorities.contains(authority.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

My Form

```
public class BackendUserForm extends FormLayout { 

     TextField userName = new TextField("User name"); 
     EmailField email = new EmailField("Email");

     public BackendUserForm() {
 
       // set form fields to read-only
       if(!BackendAuthorityUtils.hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
            userName.setReadOnly(true);
            email.setReadOnly(true);
       }

        add(userName);
        add(email);
     }

     ...
}
```

Comment: Looks good to me. I believe that is exactly how to handle this.